# name is not defined i have already defined the name

Tags: python

PFB the below code I am trying to calculate tax. why do I get the `NameError: name 'tax' is not defined.`
I have defined tax below still it throws the error tax not defined.

```
    hw = float(input("Please enter total hours worked"))
    hp = float(input("Please enter the hourly rate"))

    # Pay and OT Calculations

    rp = hp * hw

    if hw == 40 or hw <40 :
        ot = 0
        tp = rp + ot

    elif hw > 40 and hw <50 :
        ot = (hw-40)*(hp*1.5)
        tp = rp + ot

    elif hw > 50 and hw < 60 :
        ot = (hw-40)*(hp*2)
        tp = rp + ot

    elif hw > 60 or hw == 60 :
        ot = (hw-40)*(hp*2.5)
        tp = rp + ot

    else :
        print ("Thanks")

    # tax Calculations

    if tp == 200 :
       tax = float((tp/100)*15)

    elif tp > 200 and tp < 300 :
         tax = ((tp-200)/100*20) + ((200/100)*15)

    elif tp >300 and tp < 400 :
         tax = ((tp-300)/100*25) + (((tp-200)-(tp-300))/100*20) + ((200/100)*15)

    elif tp >400 and tp == 400 :
         tax = ((tp-400)/100*30) + (((tp-200)-(tp-300)-(tp-400))/100*25) + (((tp-200)-(tp-300)/100)*20) + ((200/100)*15)

    else :
        print ("Thanks")

    # Printing Results

    print ("Your Salary has been credited")
    print ("Regular Pay = ", rp)
    print ("Overtime =", ot)
    print ("Gross Salary before tax deductions = ", tp)
    print ("Income Tax applicable =", tax)
```

Comment: `else` statement doesn't define `tax`

Comment: Thanks a ton , it worked but then why didn't it throw the same error for "ot" and "tp" they are also not defined in else . it worked perfect

Comment: In the case of other variables, you don't get the error because your test data does not reach the erroneous edge cases when calculating them. For example, if/else structure in `hw` calculation would never hit the last else due to the constraints of the preceding if/else cases

Comment: In your first collection of `if`s, you define `tp`. The error you described would happen if `tax` was never defined, which would only happen if `tp` is less than 200 or greater than or equal to 400 (Your last `elif` wants `tp > 400 and tp == 400` -- `tp` can never be *both* greater than **and** equal to any number. You probably meant `or`). `tp` is defined as long as `hw` is less than or equal to 60, and depends on the values of `hw` and `hp`. Try running through the math with whatever numbers you inputted for `hw` and `hp` and see why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

you are using your variables across the entire function but are only defining them in the if/else cases. This adds a lot of room for error of missing a definition somewhere within a case as in

```
...
if tp == 200 :
       tax = float((tp/100)*15)

    elif tp > 200 and tp < 300 :
         tax = ((tp-200)/100*20) + ((200/100)*15)

    elif tp >300 and tp < 400 :
         tax = ((tp-300)/100*25) + (((tp-200)-(tp-300))/100*20) + ((200/100)*15)

    elif tp >400 and tp == 400 :
         tax = ((tp-400)/100*30) + (((tp-200)-(tp-300)-(tp-400))/100*25) + (((tp-200)-(tp-300)/100)*20) + ((200/100)*15)

    else :
        # NO tax defined here
        print ("Thanks")
...
```

You should define the function-scope variables on the top of your function as:

```
    hw = float(input("Please enter total hours worked"))
    hp = float(input("Please enter the hourly rate"))

    rp = 0
    ot = 0
    tp = 0
    tax = 0

    # Pay and OT Calculations
    ...
    # Printing Results

    print ("Your Salary has been credited")
    print ("Regular Pay = ", rp)
    print ("Overtime =", ot)
    print ("Gross Salary before tax deductions = ", tp)
    print ("Income Tax applicable =", tax)
```

By setting these default values you are sure to never miss the variable `initialization` in your code and you will not need to add extra logic to handle the tax variable in the edge cases where it should not be changed (the `else` case in your question.